# Look for multiple criteria (including partial match) in a row

Tags: filter, excel-formula, array-formulas

I've got a spreadsheet with a table of 6 columns (400+ rows). A number of these have long descriptions in them. I've got a helper column to the left which I'm trying to get to show 'True' or 'False', which I then filter the table on. *I've done it this way so that I can return sub-header rows in the table that may not match the filter criteria I explain below (I have a formula that looks to see if any of the child rows match, in which case the header row shows 'True'). It also allows me to do partial matches easily*

[Screenshot of table layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liksf.png)

The 6 rows above this table are for entering filtering criteria. The first 3 rows are for 'OR' matches - so each time a value is entered, the filter will return more values (as more matches are found). I achieve this using SUMPRODUCT(LEN($G$3:$U$5)*--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($G$3:$U$5,G9:U9)))>0, with rows 3-5 being the filter criteria. I don't really understand it - pulled it together from searching forums.

What I haven't been able to work out is how to do the 'AND' part - where each additional criteria entered into rows 6-8 would reduce the values returned.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You say the data table has 6 columns, yet your formula is referencing columns G thru U (15 columns). Also, your screenshot shows the first row of data on what appears to be row 12, yet your formula is referencing row 9... just saying, this is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If your data table does not contain any blank cells, try the following formula:

```
=SUM(NOT(ISBLANK($G$3:$U$5))*ISNUMBER(SEARCH($G$3:$U$5, G9:U9)))
+PRODUCT(COUNTA($G$6:$U$8)*ISNUMBER(SEARCH($G$6:$U$8, G9:U9)))>0
```

If blank cells are present, modify the formula as follows:

```
=SUM(NOT(ISBLANK($G$3:$U$5))*ISNUMBER(SEARCH($G$3:$U$5, G9:U9)))
+PRODUCT(COUNTA($G$6:$U$8)*ISNUMBER(SEARCH($G$6:$U$8, IF(ISBLANK(G9:U9)," ",G9:U9))))>0
```

**NOTE:** with older versions of Excel, be sure to use Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

**Example Results:**

[image: sum_product.png]

Both of the above formulas use AND logic to meet ALL criteria entered in rows 6 to 8. For example, using criteria "**Type 1**" in `K6` and "**Type 2**" in `K7` will return NO matches, because it's impossible for a single value in the "*Type*" column to be both. If you need the AND logic to be evaluated row by row instead, try something like this:

```
=SUM(NOT(ISBLANK($G$3:$U$5))*ISNUMBER(SEARCH($G$3:$U$5, G9:U9)))
+PRODUCT(COUNTA($G$6:$U$6)*ISNUMBER(SEARCH($G$6:$U$6, G9:U9)))
+PRODUCT(COUNTA($G$7:$U$7)*ISNUMBER(SEARCH($G$7:$U$7, G9:U9)))
+PRODUCT(COUNTA($G$8:$U$8)*ISNUMBER(SEARCH($G$8:$U$8, G9:U9)))>0
```

Best of luck!